# Running multiple services on one dedicated server with static IP

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ftp, rutorrent

I've been tinkering with a dedicated server running on Ubuntu. The basic setup LAMP, SSH is no problem, works great.

But when I install multiple applications as a service I get stuck in getting access to those. For example a website is on port 80, airtime is on port 8000, FTP 20/21 and so on.

I ran in to problems by installing `rutorrent` for example (following [this tutorial](http://torrentfreaknews.blogspot.nl/2013/06/how-to-install-rtorrentrutorrent-on.html)). It has its own folder and virtual host set up in Apache i.e. `/var/www/rutorrent` and with it's own port 9090. No matter what I try, can't reach its own `index.html`.

I also forward the ports and IP on my router, no firewall for the moment. My understanding of running multiple applications on one server is that as long each app has it's own port, you can run them side by side:

```
192.168.1.101:21 FTP
192.168.1.101:80 Website
192.168.1.101:8000 Airtime
192.168.1.101:9090 ruTorrent
```

And so on... Am I right to populate my server this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run multiple services as you describe, this is what "ports" are for in fact.

See: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

My guess would be a permissions problem, does you rtorrent server and apache BOTH have at least read/write (for torrent) access to /var/www/rutorrent ?

Comment: Thanks! Excellent link and your suggestion was indeed the problem.. auch.. :)